# Seeing how a user is related to me or others

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

I'd find it useful if on the profile page for a given user I could see how they relate to me. For example: "You answered the following questions for this user: ..." This could apply to anything like comments on each others answers/questions, comments on the same answer/question, answering each others questions, votes you cast for/against the user (but not vice versa) etc.

Comment: Huh. Not sure how this would work, but it might be interesting.

Comment: Agree with @Linuxios - this sounds interesting. The only change I'd make is to not show what votes you cast for/against the user - some people might start looking here just to see whether they liked/disliked another of the same user's post - and do the same action on  a possibly better/worse post they come across

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ actually I agree, that could lead to bias in voting. Good point

Answer (score 6):

You might find this SEDE query useful:

[Have we met?](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/253301/have-we-met)

For example:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/253301/have-we-met?MyId=32943&TheirId=39992

Comment: Good one, this is sort of along the lines I was thinking of