# Some questions about search

Tags: support, comments, answers, search, users

1. I want to search questions answered by me and some another user. How can I do this? I don't see an "and" operator.
2. Is there a way to search through comments (answers under which there is some comment text)?

Comment: For 1., [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252925/295232) may work. For 2., see [How can I search for specific comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23771/295232)

Comment: For #1, do you want to find questions answered by you _and at least one other user_? Or do you want questions answered by you and a specific other user?

Comment: @cocomac Specific.

Comment: @oleedd I'm not sure how off the top of my head, but it's likely possible using [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/). I don't know exactly what the SQL needed would be, but I'd guess it is possible

Comment: @Glorfindel 1. Unfortunately, it doesn't work (if I do correctly). 2. I know how to search in Google) I mean the direct search. Maybe something new since 2009...

Comment: @oleedd: To search comments, you can use [this data explorer query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210112/187824)

Answer (score 4):

> I want to search questions answered by me and some another user. How to do this? I don't see an "and" operator.

This is not possible via normal search, so you have to resort to tools like the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). With a bit of SQL, you can write queries like [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1700052/questions-with-an-answer-by-two-specific-users?UserId1=10412361&UserId2=12079044); you can change the user IDs and the site you want to search on:

[image]

Comment: Can you make it work with nicks instead of id's?

Comment: Possible to search just with `search?q=`?

Comment: Nicknames are not unique, and it would make the query slower (two extra joins), so that's bad practice. And it's unfortunately not possible with regular search ...

Comment: I want to try with nicknames. How to modify? Ideal variant: id or nickname. Possible?

Comment: You'll need to join both `Posts` tables with `Users` (not unlike [this page in the awesome tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial/query-joins) and filter on`DisplayName`.

Comment: I don't know `sql` and can't do this. Can you make it work with both id's and nicknames?

Comment: I could, but as I said, it's bad practice, so it would reduce the quality of my answer.

Comment: I think I will accept it after that. For now, I have to get id's to use it, not handy.

Comment: And it will still work with id's...

Comment: *so it would reduce the quality of my answer* — you can make a new query for this (no any reducing).

Comment: It shows duplicates if another user or/and I have more than 1 answer (more answers, more duplicates). Is it fixable?

Comment: Now *that* is a good suggestion, and I've implemented it now.

Comment: Please make a new query for nicknames. You can give it in a comment if you don't want to change the answer.